# Magento 2 custom customer attribute data not saved

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer, customer-attribute

We are working on Magento 2.2 create custom attribute **seller_id** for customer,this attribute is created successfully.

But we can not display this attribute when loading the customer data.

```
<?php
namespace Kh\Hello\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'seller_id', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Seller Id',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'seller_id')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

    }
}
```

when load customer collection this attribute is not display.

```
$collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                   ->addAttributeToFilter("email", array("eq" => "gg@gmail.com"));
```

Also loading customer and accessing this attribute data not display.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure that the attribute is in the customer_form_attribute table.

Additionally, check that the is_system attribute value is set to 0.

Also, you have assigned that attribute to "adminhtml_customer" form only. Might be it will not load attribute on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try also to add attribute to Default attribute set something like this:

```
$customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
$attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

$attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
$attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

$attribute->addData([
    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
    'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
    'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_edit']
]);
$attribute->save();
```